# azure bicep modules - condition on existing resource - how to?

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-bicep

I am trying to deploy different types of secrets using modules. The idea is to have "general" secrets, and the "storage related" secrets where the secret value is not passed directly but retrieved from properties of the storage. I designed the following `Secret.bicep`:

```c
param keyVaultName string
param secretName string

@secure()
param secretValue string

@allowed([
  'general'
  'storage_conn_string'
])
param secretType string = 'general'

@description('For secretType = storage_*, this is how we will be passing storage name')
param storageAccountName string = 'dummyvalue123'


resource kv 'Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults@2023-02-01' existing = {
  name: keyVaultName
}

resource secret'Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/secrets@2023-02-01' = if (secretType == 'general') {
  parent: kv
  name: secretName
  properties: {
    value: secretValue
  }
}

// for secrets related to storage we will need to have storage resource:
resource storageAccount 'Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts@2023-01-01' existing = if (startsWith(secretType, 'storage_')) {
  name: storageAccountName
}

// storage connection string
resource secret_conn_string 'Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/secrets@2023-02-01' = if (secretType == 'storage_conn_string') {
  parent: kv
  name: secretName
  properties: {
    value: 'DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=${storageAccountName};EndpointSuffix=${environment().suffixes.storage};AccountKey=${storageAccount.listKeys().keys[0].value}'
  }
}
```

Now in `main.bicep` I have the following:

```c
@secure()
param secretValueAPIkey string

...

module secretStorageDataConnectionString 'modules/KeyVault/Secret.bicep' = {
  // this needs to be a module and not a resource because we need 
  // to pass a connection string to storage, and storage is declared here as a module
  // so we cannot use the listKeys() method
  name: 'secretStorageDataConnectionString'
  params: {
    keyVaultName: kv.outputs.keyVaultName
    secretType : 'storage_conn_string'
    storageAccountName: storageAccount4data.outputs.dtls.name
    secretName: 'secretStorageDataConnectionString'
    secretValue: 'some-dummy-secret-value' //passing dummy value, we will retrieve it in via the module
  }
}

module secretAPIkey 'modules/KeyVault/Secret.bicep' = {
  name: 'secretAPIkey'
  params: {
    keyVaultName: kv.outputs.keyVaultName
    secretType: 'general'
    secretName: 'secretAPIkey'
    secretValue: secretValueAPIkey
  }
}
```

(Please note I skipped some bits e.g. the keyvault module, or storage module. They get deployed with no issue.)

EDIT:

storage account is created as a **module**:

```c
module storageAccount4data 'modules/Storage/StorageAccount.bicep' = {
  name: storageAccount4dataName
  params: {
    location: location
    storageAccountName: storageAccount4dataName
  }
}
```

StorageAccount.bicep:

```c
param storageAccountName string

...

resource storageAccount 'Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts@2023-01-01' = {
  name: storageAccountName
  location: location
  sku: {
    name: storageAccountSkuName
  }
  kind: 'StorageV2'
}

output dtls object = {
  id: storageAccount.id
  name: storageAccount.name
  apiVersion: storageAccount.apiVersion
}
```

END OF EDIT

Now when deploying, the `secretStorageDataConnectionString` module is created without any issues, but the `secreAPIkey` module returns an error:

```json
\"target\": \"/subscriptions/<...>/providers/Microsoft.Resources/deployments/secretAPIkey\"
\"message\": \"The Resource 'Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/dummyvalue123' under resource group <resource-group> was not found. ..."
```

For some reason the storage resource is still attempted to be created despite the if condition...?

I also tested using:

```c
//secret.bicep
param storageAccountName string = ''

...

resource storageAccount 'Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts@2023-01-01' existing = if (!empty(storageAccountName)) {
  name: storageAccountName
}
```

but this one also does not seem to evaluate correctly...

Comment: All resources are existed in same resource group? @average.everyman

Comment: Why are you iffing on an existing resource? I would simply remove the if on it.

Comment: @JanneP because I only need it for specific type of secret. And yes, all in the same resource group

Comment: @average.everyman Remove `existing` keyword and only try with the if condition once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is with the `if` condition as it is not correctly evaluated in the bicep code.

Usually, if the `storageAccountName` argument is left blank during deployment, the storage resource will not be created. If the `storageAccountName` argument is not empty at deployment time, the storage resource is created even if it isn't specified in the `secretAPIkey` module.

When you deploy the bicep code, make sure the storage account name is not empty even though it is provided to the module.

Everything worked as expected after giving the storage account name with the same code you used.

`param  storageAccountName  string`

secret.bicep:

```bash
param keyVaultName string = 'newvaultj'
param secretName string
@secure()
param secretValue string 
@allowed([
  'general'
  'storage_conn_string'
])
param secretType string = 'general'

@description('For secretType = storage_*, this is how we will be passing storage name')
param storageAccountName string = 'xxxxx'


resource kv 'Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults@2023-02-01' existing = {
  name: keyVaultName
}

resource secret'Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/secrets@2023-02-01' = if (secretType == 'general') {
  parent: kv
  name: secretName
  properties: {
    value: secretValue
  }
}

resource storageAccount 'Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts@2023-01-01' existing = if (startsWith(secretType, 'storage_')) {
  name: storageAccountName
}

resource secret_conn_string 'Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/secrets@2023-02-01' = if (secretType == 'storage_conn_string') {
  parent: kv
  name: secretName
  properties: {
    value: 'DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=${storageAccountName};EndpointSuffix=${environment().suffixes.storage};AccountKey=${storageAccount.listKeys().keys[0].value}'
  }
}
```

main.bicep:

```bash
@secure()
param secretValueAPIkey string = 'newapikey'
param keyVaultName string = 'newvaultj'
param storageAccountName string = 'xxxxx'

module secretStorageDataConnectionString 'secret.bicep' = {
  name: 'secretStorageDataConnectionString'
  params: {
    keyVaultName: kv.name
    secretType : 'storage_conn_string'
    storageAccountName: storageAccount.name
    secretName: 'secretStorageDataConnectionString'
    secretValue: 'some-dummy-secret-value'
  }
}

module secretAPIkey 'secret.bicep' = {
  name: 'secretAPIkey'
  params: {
    keyVaultName: kv.name
    secretType: 'general'
    secretName: 'secretAPIkey'
    secretValue: secretValueAPIkey
  }
}
```

Updated code:

```bash
param secretValueAPIkey string = 'newapikey'
param keyVaultName string = 'newvaultj'
param storageAccountName string = 'jaxxxx9920'
param location string = resourceGroup().location
resource kv 'Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults@2023-02-01' existing = {
  name: keyVaultName
}
module storageAccount4data 'StorageAccount.bicep' = {
  name: storageAccountName
  params: {
    location: location
    storageAccountName: storageAccountName
  }
}

module secretStorageDataConnectionString 'secret.bicep' = {
  name: 'secretStorageDataConnectionString'
  params: {
    keyVaultName: kv.name
    secretType : 'storage_conn_string'
    storageAccountName: storageAccount4data.name
    secretName: 'secretStorageDataConnectionString'
    secretValue: 'some-dummy-secret-value' //passing dummy value, we will retrieve it in via the module
  }
}

module secretAPIkey 'secret.bicep' = {
  name: 'secretAPIkey'
  params: {
    keyVaultName: kv.name
    secretType: 'general'
    secretName: 'secretAPIkey'
    secretValue: secretValueAPIkey
  }
}
```

*Deployment succeeded:*

[image]

[image]

Comment: thanks, however this does not seem to work for me, still getting the same error. Perhaps some clarification / useful information (please see the edit) - I am creating storage account as module, maybe this has some impact. I tried to pass an initial dummy value in StorageAccount.bicep but it did not help...

Comment: By using module to create a storage account as you provided, I am able to deploy it successfully as [shown](https://i.imgur.com/IW01QMv.png). @average.everyman

Comment: Updated in the above answer. @average.everyman

Comment: Apologies for the late reply, was away in the last few days. I tested the approach with providing initial default names for the storage but I still did not manage to get it to work as advised I am afraid. I decided to switch instead to separate secret.bicep templates per type of a secret (depending if a secret needs a storage or not) . Thank you for your efforts @Jahnavi